# В чём отличие 1u от 1?

Tags: c++

Есть ли принципиальное отличие между `1u` и `1`, если я работаю с битами? Есть ли side-effects?

```
unsigned int dim;
unsigned int size;
```

...

```
typedef short int base_t;
typedef unsigned char size_base_t;
size_base_t start_bit = this->dim * index;bits
size_base_t start_bit_vector = start_bit % size;
base_t start_mask = (1u << start_bit_vector) - 1;
```

Comment: Теоретически - да. Потому что нормальная работа с битами гарантируется для unsigned. *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Можете показать конкретный код?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat updated

Comment: в данном случаи нет никакой разницы. Код отличается при работе с отрицательными значениями

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В данном случае отличия не будет. Потому что нормальная работа с битами гарантируется для unsigned. Будут отличия при работе с отрицательными значениями

Comment: Не могли бы Вы добавить в свой ответ какие-то ссылки на источники информации? Сейчас ответ не вызывает доверия, другим участникам придется искать иные источники информации, даже если наткнутся на Ваше сообщение. Ну и очередь проверок ругается)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov я сформировал его из комметариев участников, которым доверяю. Эти участники имеют соответствующие метки и их мнение экспертно.